# Testing a stream in node-unit, reports undone tests

Tags: node.js, nodeunit

I'm testing a stream I coded using node-unit.  The first test works, but the second test fails:

```
FAILURES: Undone tests (or their setups/teardowns): 
- testVideo
```

I think it is because something async is going on...not sure.  Here is what I'm doing:

```
 rs
   .pipe(theStreamBeingTested)
   .pipe(through(captureActualResult, assertCorrectnessOfResult(test, expected)));
```

in assertCorrectnessOfResult I do my assertion then call: test.done

However that doesn't seem to work when I export more than one test...